# Hapijs crumb plugin give me undefined crumb

Tags: plugins, hapi.js

I'm trying to use crumb plugin in my project to get a token [crumb plugin](https://github.com/hapijs/crumb)
I have imported it as a plugin. In the jade template I get it in that way

```
input(type='hidden', name='crumb', value='#{crumb}')
```

but the value is `undefined`. Why I get that value? Should I set any settings? According to the examples of the developer, it seems so easy

Answer (score 0):

When cors is enabled, crumb token isn't generated. The developer has updated in order to generate crumb when cors is true